# jQuery open close two separate div one by one with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to open and close a two separate div one by one with same class.

The below example when I first click `opentab` **content 1** will open first time and second click **content 2** will open second time.

Closing the div one by one as follow content 2 and content 1.

[Reference link](https://dore-jquery.coloredstrategies.com/Dashboard.Default.html)

Comment for further clarification. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".opentab").on('click', function () {
   $('.tabcontent').toggle('show');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="opentab" id="opentab">Open tab</a>

<div class="tabcontent">
    Content 1
</div>
<div class="tabcontent">
    Content 2
</div>
```

Comment: I'm a bit unclear, especially this sentence: *"Closing the div as follow on same click content 2 first and content 1 second."*. Each time the `Open Tab` link is clicked, only **one** item should appear (the next). Is that correct?

Comment: @TylerRoper similar like this menu toggle https://dore-jquery.coloredstrategies.com/Dashboard.Default.html

Comment: Hmm. [Like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/09obd1c3/)

Comment: Yes.  but I want open the div also one by one.

Comment: @TylerRoper checkout this like as per my reference https://i.imgur.com/RtkRy13.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you'll need to know which "direction" you're going (i.e. if the next click should be *opening* or *closing* items), I'd suggest using a boolean variable to keep track. Let's call that `isClosing`.

Logic-wise, you are always doing one of two things:

- If *closing*, hide the *last* visible
- If *opening*, show the *first* hidden

(Comments included in the code)

```js
let isClosing = true;  //We need to know if we're "closing" or "opening" the items

$(".opentab").on('click', function() {

  $(".tabcontent").finish();                //Skip animations if pressed rapidly

  const $elementToToggle = isClosing 
    ? $('.tabcontent:visible').last()       //If "closing", toggle the last visible
    : $('.tabcontent:hidden').first();      //Otherwise, toggle the first hidden

  $elementToToggle.toggle('show', () => {                         //Callback to wait for animation to complete
    if (!$(".tabcontent:visible").length) isClosing = false;      //All hidden, switch to "opening"
    else if (!$(".tabcontent:hidden").length) isClosing = true;   //All visible, switch to "closing"
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="opentab" id="opentab">Open tab</a>

<div class="tabcontent">Content 1</div>
<div class="tabcontent">Content 2</div>
<div class="tabcontent">Content 3</div>
<div class="tabcontent">Content 4</div>
```

Comment: Jitter clicking `.opentab` causes a stuck `.tabcontent`

Comment: @mark04 Was editing the answer to address that as you commented :)

Comment: @TylerRoper is there any possible to add/remove class method?

Answer (score 0):

Hide your second `div` and your toggle work.

```js
$('.tabcontent').eq(1).hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".opentab").on('click', function() {
    $('.tabcontent').toggle('show');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="opentab" id="opentab">Open tab</a>

<div class="tabcontent">
  Content 1
</div>
<div class="tabcontent">
  Content 2
</div>
```

Alternative set counter with hide and use toggle.

```js
//$('.tabcontent').eq(1).hide();
var counter = 0;
$(".opentab").on('click', function() {
  $('.tabcontent').eq(counter).hide();
  counter++;
  if (counter > 1) // Reset counter
    counter = 0;
  $('.tabcontent').toggle('show');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="opentab" id="opentab">Open tab</a>

<div class="tabcontent">
  Content 1
</div>
<div class="tabcontent">
  Content 2
</div>
```